# Angular2 EventEmitter does not complete after invoking .error

Tags: angular, rxjs, eventemitter

I have an `EventEmitter` that inform a user that notify a component that the state of the application has changed.

This event inform whether a user who is trying to authenticate has been successful.

```
private emitAuthStatus(success: boolean) {
    if (success) {
        this.locationWatcher.emit({
            authenticated: this.authenticated,
            token: this._authData.token,
            expires: this.expires
        });
    } else {
        this.locationWatcher.error();
    }

    this.locationWatcher.complete();
}
```

Now when I call `.emit` followed by `.complete` everything works properly.
But if I call `.error`, the `.complete` throws an `ObjectUnsubscribedError`.

What is `.error` intended for and am what do I do incorrectly in this code?

Comment: But why do you call error() and complete()  here? you should call/use them where you are subscribing to `locationWatcher observer` in the component.

Comment: Does an error mean that something went wrong with the event, or that the event is raising a special type of event? When I look at the documentation it seems to be raising a special type of events, but surely it should not mean that the `EventEmitter` is no longer subscribed?

Comment: I don't think `error()` and `complete()` are supposed to be used at all. `EventEmitter` currently extends `Observable` but that is an implementation detail and is expected to change at any time without any deprecation phase. Use `EventEmitter` only for `@Output()` only in components and only use the method `emit()`.

Comment: Update your code with the component which uses this. So we'll be able to tell you more.

Comment: Thank you both I have changed my code to only use the .emit and send the failure information in the emitted object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code to not use `.error` and `.complete` which are not meant to be used to transit information.

```
private emitAuthStatus() {
    this.locationWatcher.emit({
        // The .authenticated allow us to know if the EventEmitter is a success
        authenticated: this.authenticated, 
        token: this._authData.token,
        expires: this.expires
    });
}
```